# Layering JPanels in java?

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to java, so be gentle.

I'm adding multiple JPanels to a JFrame, and i'm wanting them layered, i.e. one ontop of the other, both being different sizes.

Query: Why do i have to add the panel I want on top first? Surely, it would be the other way round?

```
frame.add(panel2);
frame.add(panel1);
```

i'd of thought it'd be the other way round, but if i do it that way, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See method of container.

```
/**
 * Returns the z-order index of the component inside the container. 
 * The higher a component is in the z-order hierarchy, the lower
 * its index.  The component with the lowest z-order index is
 * painted last, above all other child components.
 *
 * @param comp the component being queried
 * @return  the z-order index of the component; otherwise 
 *          returns -1 if the component is <code>null</code>
 *          or doesn't belong to the container 
 * @see #setComponentZOrder(java.awt.Component, int)
 * @since 1.5
 */
public int getComponentZOrder(Component comp) {
        }
```

Comment: Are you the same Stanislav from the Oracle/Sun forums? If so, great to see you here!

Comment: Yes:-) I'm the same. But all my >1000 dukes are lost there... on the old SUN's forums.